# How to copy an array to another with some logic

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to write code that copies one array to another. Sequentially copied all elements

1. greater than 0,
2. then successively all the elements equal to 0,
3. and then successively all the elements is less than 0.

Here's my failed attempt to implement this task:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int randNum = random.nextInt(600) - 350;
        arr[i] = randNum;
    }
    int[] newArr = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > 0)
        {
            System.arraycopy(arr, arr[i], newArr, 0, 100);

            // arraycopy() Not works!
            // I tryed to compare each element in array greater than 0 
            // and copy it to newArr

        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
```

Why `System.arraycopy` is not working?

Comment: `System.arraycopy()` cannot filter what is being copied. To only copy positive values, *you* have to check that, so you need 3 loops, like you said: *First*, copy positive values. *Second*, copy zero values. *Third*, copy negative values. Three steps = three loops.

Comment: By "copy" I mean assign values from one array to the other, e.g. `newArr[j] = arr[i]`, one element at a time, as you check their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, you are copying array per-cell! so the inner loop should look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr = new int[100], newArr = new int[100];
    int j=0;
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        int randNum = random.nextInt(600) - 350;
        arr[i] = randNum;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > 0){
            newArr[j]=arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    // and add code for numbers=0 and less than 0. So you should append code:
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0){
            newArr[j]=arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < 0){
            newArr[j]=arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
}
```

Comment: You can't declare `j` in the `for` loop, because you won't then be able to use it in the next two loops copying zero and negative values.

Comment: it is a local declaration. the `j` variable is garbaged at the end of the for loop and redeclared in the next one. This is done for better code readability and modularization. If you want you can declare it once at the top of the code.

Comment: If the next loop redeclares `j`, how would you assign the initial value? Where should the first zero or negative value be placed in `newArr`?

Comment: first loop works, but if I do next loop arr[i] < 0, I got error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Andreas Understood the bug you signaled. `j=newArr.length-1` would return always 99 since the array is declared `new int[100];` so there is no way to know the last insertion index.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class A{
       public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       int[] arr = new int[100];
       Random random = new Random();
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
       {
           int randNum = random.nextInt(600) - 350;
           arr[i] = randNum;
       }
       int[] newArr = new int[100];
       int j=0;
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

       {

           if (arr[i] > 0)
           {
               System.arraycopy(arr, i, newArr, j,1);
               // arraycopy() Not works!
               // I tryed to compare each element in array greater than 0 
               // and copy it to newArr
               j++;
           }
       }
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

       {
           if(arr[i]==0)
           {
               System.arraycopy(arr, i, newArr, j,1);
               j++;

           }
       }
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)

{
    if(arr[i]<0)
           {
               System.arraycopy(arr, i, newArr, j,1);
               j++; 
           }

       }
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));

         }
    }
```